# ASP.NET Identity in Web Forms: how to authorize?

Tags: asp.net-identity

everyone,
I am using ASP.NET Identity that comes with visual studio 2013 express. I use Web Forms. When I create a new project, the login and signup pages are already there and its working. But my question is, when I add a new page, how do I authorize that page to only signed in users (or to a certain role). Do I use Web Site Administration Tool and web.config to do that? Or something else? Since I am not using MVC, I cannot use [Authorize] attribute.
I cannot find documents online.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would use the `Web.config` to configure access:

```
<configuration>
     <!-- Allow only Administrators to visit RoleBasedAuthorization.aspx -->    
     <location path="RoleBasedAuthorization.aspx">    
          <system.web>    
               <authorization>    
                    <allow roles="Administrators"/>
                    <deny users="*" />
               </authorization>    
          </system.web>    
     </location>    
</configuration>
```

thanks to: [Michael Perrenoud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243941/1627441)

Comment: Thank you!! Cannot believe we asked the same question!